# Passing a lambda into a function gives an "inferred" error

Tags: c#-4.0, lambda

I have a function that gets a filtered list of items based on the lambda expression I pass in. Below is an example of what I am doing. The List is an ObservableCollection of myBase and the filter I am passing in would be something like this: t => t.Data.Any()

At the moment if I replace "filter" with the above lambda it works but when I pass it in and use the local variable, filter, I get a compile error like “cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.”

```
    protected IEnumerable<myBase> GetByFilter(Expression<Func<myBase, bool>> filter)
    {
        IEnumerable<myBase> itemlList = _items.Where(filter).ToList();
        return itemlList ;
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Edit -------------------

I am trying to get a subset of the original list based on the lambda passed in. I think I may be able to get away with the lambda line returning another observableCollection rather than an IEnumerable one, if that is possible?

Edit -------------------

With help from Ruslan, I have fixed my problem. My code now compiles and looks like this:

```
protected IEnumerable<myBase> GetByFilter(Func<myBase, bool> filter) 
{ 
    IEnumerable<myBase> itemlList = _items.Where(filter).ToList(); 
    return itemlList ; 
}
```

I can pass in a filter like "t => t.Data.Any()" and get all the items etc. I just needed to drop "Expression" from the filter parameter.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question. What is relation between myBase and IdcBase? What type is _items? What type is t.Data or t.Tokens? How are you invoking the function? Finally, I believe the ObservableCollection<> does not support IQueryable<> so Expression<> filter should throw invalid arguments error instead, if that's the type of _items.

Comment: _items is the ObservableCollection<myBase>, t.Data is a string field the comment is duff data which I will remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't seehow this example would compile with Queryable extension "Where" being applied to the Enumerable collection. And it is still not entirely clear as to how it is being used. However, the following does compile and run.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestProject
{
    class myBase
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Data;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static ObservableCollection<myBase> _items;

        static IEnumerable<myBase> GetByFilter(Func<myBase, bool> filter)
        {
            IEnumerable<myBase> itemlList = _items.Where(filter).ToList();
            return itemlList;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _items = new ObservableCollection<myBase> { 
                new myBase { Id = 1, Data = "" },
                new myBase { Id = 2, Data = "Data" },
                new myBase { Id = 3, Data = "More Data" }
            };

            IEnumerable<myBase> filteredList = GetByFilter(t => t.Data.Any());

            foreach (var item in filteredList)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Id, item.Data);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
2: Data
3: More Data
```

Comment: Thanks for this Ruslan, your code sorted my problem. I needed to drop the “Expression” from “Expression<Func<myBase, bool>> filter”. My code now compiles and runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem *appears* to be that your filter is of type `Expression<Func<IdcBase, bool>>`, but (based on the comments) the `Where` method of the `_items` collection expects a `Func<myBase, bool>`.

I don't know what the relationship between `MyBase` and `IdcBase` is, but I am going to ***assume*** that `IdcBase` inherits from `MyBase`.

If the above assumption is correct, then you cannot filter a list of `MyBase` using a filter that expects an `IdcBase`, because it is possible that you will have entries in `_items` that are not of type `IdcBase`.  You need to either provide a filter that expects input of the type `MyBase`, or you need to first limit `_items` to those that are of type `IdcBase`:

```
protected IEnumerable<myBase> GetByFilter(Expression<Func<IdcBase, bool>> filter)
{
    IEnumerable<myBase> itemlList = _items.OfType<IdcBase>().Where(filter).ToList();
    return itemlList ;
}
```

Comment: Another typo by me. The IdcBase should have been shown as myBase. I have updated my code sample.

Comment: @Retrocoder can you add a code sample that clearly indicates what doesn't work?  The sentence "At the moment if I hardcode the lambda it works but when I pass it in and use the local variable, filter, I get an error like" makes it unclear.